# Hibernate automatically delete many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have a List that supposed to be many-to-many (bidirectional)

This is the Filter class:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=Serving.class)
@JoinTable(name = "BRIDGE_SERV_FILTER", joinColumns={
    @JoinColumn(name="filter_id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="serving_id")})
private List<Serving> servings;
public List<Serving> getServing() { return this.servings; }
public void setServing(List<Serving> servings) { this.servings = servings; }
```

and this is the Serving class:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=Filter.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "BRIDGE_SERV_FILTER", joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="serving_id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="filter_id")})
    private List<Filter> filters;
    public List<Filter> getFilters() { return filters;}
    public void setFilters(List<Filter> filters) { this.filters = filters;}
```

Then I supposed to call something to get all the filters from a serving, this is what I do (serv is of type Serving):

```
List<Filter> filters = serv.getFilters();

//iterate from all filter
for(Filter allf : allFilter)
{
    boolean mark_this = false;
    //..and matched the currently-iterated-all-filters with filter from
    //which the serving got
    for(com.pos.model.Filter f : filters)
    {
        //if matched, mark this current filter
        if (allf.getId().equals(f.getId()))
            mark_this = true;
    }
    tmodel.addRow(new Object[] { allf.getName(), mark_this });
}
```

that method is defined in the model, and it is static. so, when the form load, it calls like jTable.setTableModel(Filter.toTableModel(thisServing));

It reads, and it displayed the data. However, Hibernate also invokes delete as well:

```
Hibernate: select filter0_.filter_id as filter1_2_, filter0_.is_showable as is2_2_, filter0_.name as name2_ from DIM_FILTER filter0_ where is_showable=true
Hibernate: select filters0_.serving_id as serving1_4_1_, filters0_.filter_id as filter2_6_1_, filter1_.filter_id as filter1_2_0_, filter1_.is_showable as is2_2_0_, filter1_.name as name2_0_ from BRIDGE_SERV_FILTER filters0_ inner join DIM_FILTER filter1_ on filters0_.filter_id=filter1_.filter_id where filters0_.serving_id=?
Hibernate: delete from BRIDGE_SERV_FILTER where serving_id=?
```

In fact, I don't do any delete at all, and I don't ask hibernate to delete anything. Something that I don't understand might occur... how to prevent Hibernate from deletion? or there is anything that I done wrongly?

Comment: it is interesting somehow that, if only getFilters() is invoked, nothing delete occured. however, if I start to read the filter and then do the addRow(), so the delete will occur.

Comment: even if I use set, still is automatically deleted once I want to do 'get'. please help...

Answer (score 2):

There is somewhere in your code where you must clear the filters collection of a service, or set this collection to null. Hibernate makes this change persistent.

Also note that your mapping is wrong, which is a reason why you see strange behaviors. Instead of having a bidirectional ManyToMany, you have two, unrelated, unidirectional ManyToMany, both using the same join table. One of the side must be chosen as the inverse of the other side. For example, if you want the filter side to be the owner of the association, you must mark the serving side as the inverse side using the `mappedBy` attribute:

```
class Filter {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "BRIDGE_SERV_FILTER", joinColumns={
    @JoinColumn(name="filter_id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="serving_id")})
    private List<Serving> servings;
}

class Serving {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "servings")
    private List<Filter> filters;
}
```

This is described in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-bidirectional).

Comment: I already changed accordingly, thank you. It somewhat still: the strange behavior  exists. I already make a simply class of the purpose of testing to fetch this bi-di. After fetching the getFilter of a Serving, it works and nothing is deleted. However, when I use form, when it initialized, it works also but it, the Hibernate, short after invoke the Delete SQL.

Comment: It happens somewhere in your code. But not in the code you posted.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I believe it so. Now I found the problem. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem actually already had on me since 8 days ago, left me helpless.

The problem reside in the way how I get the list(). So... if you have the bi-di relationship, don't do thing like:

```
Long id = getIdFromCombo();
Serving s = (Serving) session.getId(Serving.class, id).uniqueResult();
```

When on the same time you initialized the form with:

```
Public theFormName(Menu m){
  this.menu = m;
}
```

If Menu got Serving as its one-to-many, you better not query the Serving s against your session. Better to match it one-by-one in:

```
Serving s;
for(int i=0; i<this.menu.getServings().size(); i++)
{
  if(equal code) s = menu.getServings().get(i);
}
```

Then you should not have the problem like what I listed above. Which is strange. Pitfall. I wonder if anybody ever caught with this problem. Either this is my fault, or a bug, I am not sure.

Because I still don't get of why it is wrong to query against the Serving class (by help of Session) at the same time there is a menu.getServings() which could deliver your serving as well (but with a less perspective (because you get serving with where the serving.menu.id = menu.id), anyhow, doesn't matter)